# How best to work with raw (uncounted) data in d3.js?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

All examples I have seen in d3's gallery have already counted data, such as:

> ```
> letter  frequency
> A       .08167
> B       .01492
> C       .02782
> D       .04253
> ...
> ```

What if I have 'raw' data such as:

> ```
> A
> A
> B
> A
> D
> ...
> ```

Where I still have to compute the frequency so I can chart it.
What is the best way to do this?
Should I get the data into a d3.map or d3.set? Some kind of d3.nest and rollup? Or just plain JavaScript?

In my very specific case, I need to chart students' grades. I'll have other data other than the grade itself (e.g. student's name) and I'll have grades like `8.5` `8.7`that I need to chart 'as is' and rounded in the same chart.
Do I even need to be concerned with efficiency (being the calculations client-side)? I can have up to 100000 rows of data or as little as 30 or 4 rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [histogram layout](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Histogram-Layout) for this. See the example [here](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3048450).

Comment: The histogram layout turned out to be exactly what I needed. It takes my data and sorts it into bins according to my specification (number of bins, how to divide, etc). I think this is the most flexible solution, however, I stumbled with the histogram layout a lot at first with small presentation issues. I ended up using another solution for some time (until I understood histogram layout better):
 `var valuesHash = d3.nest().key(function(d){return d.grade;}).entries(data);`
  and plot it using `x(d.key)`and `y(d.values.length)`